# Composer : Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I am trying to install rocketeer to my laravel project, and i get this error :

```
> composer require --dev anahkiasen/rocketeer
Using version ^2.2 for anahkiasen/rocketeer
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Conclusion: remove laravel/framework v5.4.26
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.26
    - anahkiasen/rocketeer 2.2.0 requires illuminate/log ~4.2 -> satisfiable by illuminate/log[v4.2.1, v4.2.12, v4.2.16, v4.2.17, v4.2.2, v4.2.3, v4.2.4, v4.2.5, v4.2.6, v4.2.7, v4.2.8, v4.2.9].
    - anahkiasen/rocketeer 2.2.1 requires illuminate/log ~4.2 -> satisfiable by illuminate/log[v4.2.1, v4.2.12, v4.2.16, v4.2.17, v4.2.2, v4.2.3, v4.2.4, v4.2.5, v4.2.6, v4.2.7, v4.2.8, v4.2.9].
    - anahkiasen/rocketeer 2.2.2 requires illuminate/log ~4.2 -> satisfiable by illuminate/log[v4.2.1, v4.2.12, v4.2.16, v4.2.17, v4.2.2, v4.2.3, v4.2.4, v4.2.5, v4.2.6, v4.2.7, v4.2.8, v4.2.9].
    - anahkiasen/rocketeer 2.2.3 requires illuminate/log ~4.2 -> satisfiable by illuminate/log[v4.2.1, v4.2.12, v4.2.16, v4.2.17, v4.2.2, v4.2.3, v4.2.4, v4.2.5, v4.2.6, v4.2.7, v4.2.8, v4.2.9].
    - anahkiasen/rocketeer 2.2.4 requires illuminate/log ~4.2 -> satisfiable by illuminate/log[v4.2.1, v4.2.12, v4.2.16, v4.2.17, v4.2.2, v4.2.3, v4.2.4, v4.2.5, v4.2.6, v4.2.7, v4.2.8, v4.2.9].
    - anahkiasen/rocketeer 2.2.5 requires illuminate/log ~4.2 -> satisfiable by illuminate/log[v4.2.1, v4.2.12, v4.2.16, v4.2.17, v4.2.2, v4.2.3, v4.2.4, v4.2.5, v4.2.6, v4.2.7, v4.2.8, v4.2.9].
    - don't install illuminate/log v4.2.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.26
    - don't install illuminate/log v4.2.12|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.26
    - don't install illuminate/log v4.2.16|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.26
    - don't install illuminate/log v4.2.17|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.26
    - don't install illuminate/log v4.2.2|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.26
    - don't install illuminate/log v4.2.3|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.26
    - don't install illuminate/log v4.2.4|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.26
    - don't install illuminate/log v4.2.5|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.26
    - don't install illuminate/log v4.2.6|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.26
    - don't install illuminate/log v4.2.7|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.26
    - don't install illuminate/log v4.2.8|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.26
    - don't install illuminate/log v4.2.9|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.26
    - Installation request for laravel/framework (locked at v5.4.26, required as 5.4.*) -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.4.26].
    - Installation request for anahkiasen/rocketeer ^2.2 -> satisfiable by anahkiasen/rocketeer[2.2.0, 2.2.1, 2.2.2, 2.2.3, 2.2.4, 2.2.5].
```

Here is my composer.json file:

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.6.4",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.2",
        "laravel/framework": "5.4.*",
        "laravel/tinker": "~1.0",
        "phpunit/php-code-coverage": "^4.0",
        "maatwebsite/excel": "~2.1.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~5.7"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "php artisan key:generate"
        ],
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postInstall",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postUpdate",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true,
        "optimize-autoloader": true
    }
}
```

Comment: what is your PHP version ?

Comment: Php 7.0.12 is my version

Comment: check from command line you have open to use composer to know which version composer is getting ?